# Approximate searching against a list of strings

Tags: java, algorithm, string, java-me

So yes, I read about how edit distance can be used between strings to decide how "close" are two string to each other. This algorithm, implemented as a Dynamic problem takes O(mn) time, where m and n are the lengths of the text and pattern respectively. So if I have to match a string against 5000 odd other strings, it's gonna take a LOT of time, which on my application is simply not acceptable. Is there are faster solution that can be implemented? I don't mind trading storage space for time.

I have seen an application called "Swype" on Android, which does something similar. It searches your query against it's own database and suggests results. How does that work so quickly?

**Note**: Please don't suggest frameworks like Lucene, because I cannot run then on J2ME.

Comment: Is this for typing corrections? Are you sure you need something faster than Levenshtein distance? 5000 doesn't sound so bad if they're short dictionary words.

Comment: This is basically for searching an article name(user query) against a list of articles which are pre-populated. Now, since the user might enter incorrect queries, the search must suggest the nearest match or a "no-match" if none found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

splix's answer is good.  As another option (for very large string sets), you may want to consider using an n-gram representation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

These are used for approximate pattern matching in a lot of database packages since they are fast and easy to implement using conventional indexing methodologies.

Answer (score 1):

We had used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm for nearly same thing, and it worked fine for us.

There is few Java implementations of it, you can find them on the web

PS you can also check other string-matching algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: splix, by "we" do you mean Swype?

Comment: Looks like the Aho algorithm matches many keywords against a text. In my case I have one keyword against many text. So does the process just reverse? That is, all the text I have now become keywords and the single keywords becomes the text?

Comment: Oops, seems that I misunderstand your questions :( Yes, this algorithm is useful only when you have few thousands of patterns against one incoming text to check. You can reverse it, as you suggests, but i'm not sure that it will be best option. Probably n-grams can help you better

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the texts you are comparing. In the following I present two speed-up approches within the original edit-distance framework.

We once had the same task where we combined a short word sequence (something like 10-30 chars) against a dictionary of >300k short sentences (also 10-30 chars each). In this case the following approach saved us a lot of time:

- sort the dictionary of target strings (this has to be done only once)
- when you build the n*m table of string `i` you can reuse the table from string `i-1` since most of the lines are in common.

E.g. if you have the two strings `"list of strings"` and next `"list of words"` you can reuse the first 8 lines of your table and only have to recalculate 5 (both strings have 8 characters in common). This way we saved up to 70-80% of the runtime with only small changes to our code.

If instead you have few long texts the first approach won't save you much. But in this case you expect that only few entries have small edit distance while all others have a huge distance. Since the n*m table is somewhat monotonic in each direction (i.e. the minimum of each line is monotonic, as well as for each column) you can stop the calculation once you reach a pre-specified threshold. You can even save the intermediate results and "restart" the calculation (with a higher bound) if you do not find a solution within your initial threshold.

Comment: Those are some really cool optimizations with the reuse of the table there. My data set is sorted lexicographically. But the reuse of string (i-1)'s table I guess largely depends on the type of the data set. I don't know exactly how much will that help me. I intend to keep the threshold at a definite value which I will probably know better by testing at various values (i.e. which value suits me best). I'll vote your answer up, since I really like the reuse of the table concept.

Answer (score 0):

Its also a matter of how you define "close". If you are not insisting on written, but spoken would also work, I could suggest `soundex`. Its a very fast algorithm to see if 2 words a phonetic close.

Comment: I say "close" in the context of the aforementioned algorithm. Soundex sounds really cool though. I'll have a look at it.